# Create multiple logins in the same browser at same time

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-model, yii2-user

I want to create multiple logins at a time on the same browser, like admin and user.

For that we are using different models like LoginForm.php and Adminlogin.php and different identity classes, i.e. User.php and Admin.php. But when we login with admin and at that time we want to login as a user admin gets logout and user gets login.

But I want to login both admin and user at same time. How to do that?

Comment: store them in different session like $_SESSION['admin'], $_SESSION['user'] .

Comment: Add two `user` type components - like `user` for regular users and `admin` for admins.

Comment: In database put something like **Rank**. And then put 1 for normal users, and 2 for example for admin. Then when logged in: check if the number is 1 or 2 and do stuff with it.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because, when a user is logged in by any role say admin, than internally like

```
$_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
$_SESSION['user_id'] = logged in user id;
```

when you logged in again with a diff user then the value in `$_SESSION['user_id']` is overrides by the new logged in user.

So with this approach you cannot make this happen.

The best way to achieve this is to provide a role change functionality after logged in.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a prefix,
like

```
SESSION['ADMIN_user_name']
```

is a admin user,
other is normal user.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to use [Yii 2 Advanced Application Template](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced). This way you can have a frontend and a backend, each with their own `user` component for login and it's own session.

This way you can also separate views and controllers that need to be exclusive to normal users or admin users, while also sharing through `common` models and modules that are used by both types of users.

Comment: yes, you are right in yii2 advance we an create differnt session for backed and fronted  but I am already using yii2 basic in my project